# AJAX post to Flask not working

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

Here is the AJAX call

```
$(function(){
  $("[type=submit]").click(
        function(){
            event.preventDefault()
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/query",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:$('.form-horizontal').serialize() ,
            success: function() {
                console.log('worked');
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log('didn\'t work')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

And here is the route:

```
@app.route('/query',methods=['POST'])
def query():
  return request.form['startdate']
```

I'm just testing it out right now, but I can't get anything to return from the query route.  Not `request.form` (or any specific values within such as startdate above), not `request.data`, nothing. `Request.data` is empty, and `request.form` is an empty immutablemultidict    .

Relevant HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="start_date">Start Date:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1",name='startdate'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="end_date">End Date:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2",name='enddate'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Are those commas in your input tags typos or are those actually there?

Comment: You should change your `contentType` line to `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` or to omit it completely. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917016/ajax-post-data-in-flask-view) answer.

Comment: Thanks - yes I eventually figured out that I was sending form data and trying to fetch `request.json` which did not work.  I think your approach would have been fine, I just ended up posting a JSON object instead and used `request.json` instead of `request.form`.